# Limit problem no longer works in Mathematica 11.1.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 11.1, fixed in 11.2.**

---

In *Mathematica* 11.0, the following limit,

```
Limit[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], n -> ∞]
```

gave me an answer of $e^{6 \operatorname{arctanh}(1/7)}$, which equals 64/27, but in *Mathematica* 11.1, it doesn't give an answer. Anyone else experience this problem?

Granted, with *Mathematica* 11.1.0, this does work:

```
Limit[Power[RealAbs[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)], (n)^-1], n -> ∞]
```

Giving a correct answer of 64/27.

**Update:** Due to Anjan Kumer's suggestion, I tried:

```
Limit[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], 
  n -> \[Infinity]] // PowerExpand
```

But it gave an incorrect answer of $-64/27$.

**Update #2:** I believe there has been some editing to my question. This question arises when we are using the Root Theorem in calculus, which requires that we investigate
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$
in order to determine if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. Due to difficulties with Mathematica's Abs command over the years, and the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, we frequently use this fact to avoid difficulties. Thus, using the Root Test to determine the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-4n}{3n+2}\right)^{3n}$$
requires that we evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(\frac{1-4n}{3n+2}\right)^{3n}\right|}$$
Now, I made a mistake and used the absolute value bars in the Writing Assistant in my input. Now, I note that the following works and gives the correct answer (I am copying and pasting an image of my input and output).

[image]

Now, notice what happens when I try to use the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ (Again, I am copying and pasting an image of my input and output).

[image]

See, the exponent 2 is inside the Sqrt brackets, not outside. However, again a different answer.

Comment: Doesn't return any answer on MMA 11.1.0. You can get an answer by using `PowerExpand`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar I tried PowerExpand, but it gave a wrong answer. See my update to my original post.

Comment: The function Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1] is complex-valued. Its limit as n approaches ComplexInfinity does not exist at all.

Comment: This will be investigated.

Comment: See also the discussion here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89054/why-doesnt-mathematica-evaluate-this-simple-limit?rq=1

Comment: This reminds me very much of this problem, and I would suggest that my answer to that problem, or rather my series of cautionary statements regarding real vs. complex limits, applies (in spirit, if not in exact content) to this question as well: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49167/why-is-this-infinite-series-wrongly-computed-by-mathematica/57023#57023

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm struggling to see what the question is, other than "Anyone else experience this problem?", which I guess comes down to, "Can others confirm this is a backslide and that I haven't messed up something?"  There is a certain amount of noise surrounding the question:  the initial mis-coding of the absolute value and the abuse of `PowerExpand` in particular.  This makes it unclear to me whether more is being sought.

**Workarounds**

The OP has already noted that coding the source problem (n-th root test) with the usual absolute value `Abs` works:

```
Limit[Power[Abs[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)], (n)^-1], n -> ∞]
(*  64/27  *)
```

Here is another workaround.

```
Limit[
 Series[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], {n, ∞, 1}],
 n -> Infinity]
(*  64/27  *)
```

And another, which perhaps is the best representation of the OP's intended computation bypassing `Abs`:

```
Limit[
 Power[Sqrt[(((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n))^2], (n)^-1], 
 n -> ∞,
 Assumptions -> n > 0 && n ∈ Integers]
(*  64/27  *)
```

**Problem with `PowerExpand`**

`PowerExpand` willy-nilly combines the exponents, effectively assuming the bases are positive.  That hypothesis is not true in this case, so the result is bogus (due to user error, not an error in *Mathematica*).  Both the incorrect `Sqrt[x]^2` and the correct `Sqrt[x^2]` replacements for `Abs[x]` for real `x` expand to the same expression, which has a limit of `-64/27` at infinity:

```
Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1] // PowerExpand     (* Sqrt[x]^2 *)
Power[Sqrt[(((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n))^2], (n)^-1] // PowerExpand   (* Sqrt[x^2] *)
(*  (1 - 4 n)^3/(2 + 3 n)^3  *)
```

When `PowerExpand` is applied to `Limit`, first the limit returns unevaluated, its arguments are expanded, and then the limit it reevaluated and returns the (correct) limit of `-64/27` for the expanded function.

Note that because the power `Power[z, (n)^-1]` is the principal value, the correct and incorrect substitutions for `Abs[x]` converge to the same value as `n -> Infinity`.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *The `fakeabs` form `Sqrt[x]^2` zigzags because `x = ((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)` alternates sign and therefore `Sqrt[x]` alternates real/imaginary.*
>
> ```
> fakeabs = ReIm@N@Table[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], {n, 150}];
> realabs = ReIm@N@Table[Power[Sqrt[(((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n))^2], (n)^-1], {n, 150}];
> limit = {ReIm[64/27]};    
> ListLinePlot[{fakeabs, realabs, limit}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
>  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRange -> All, 
>  PlotLegends -> {HoldForm@fakeabs, HoldForm@realabs, HoldForm@limit}]
> ```

I suppose it is clear that this appears to be a backslide.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the help. A lot of useful comments in your answer that were extremely helpful. Because of your answer, I will be able to edit my notebook that I have written to help my calculus students with the Root Test.

Comment: @David You're welcome.  I use the `Sqrt[x^2]` trick a lot, too.  I guess I should start trying out `RealAbs` to see if it's just as good.  (However, `Abs[x] // ComplexExpand` still expands to `Sqrt[x^2]`.)

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in 11.2:

```
Limit[Sqrt[(((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n))^2]^(1/n), n -> ∞]
   64/27

Limit[(Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2)^(1/n), n -> ∞]
   64/27

Limit[Abs[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^(1/n), n -> ∞]
   64/27
```

Answer (score 2):

Do ComplexExpand to get the right result  (Using Version 8.0 )

```
   Limit[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1] // 
            ComplexExpand, n -> Infinity]

    (*  64/27   *)
```

Comment: Also works for 11.1.0, although a few minutes are required.

Answer (score 1):

(*Mathematica 10*)

Numerically:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

NLimit[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], 
   n -> ∞] // Chop // Rationalize[#, .000001] &
(* 64/27 *)
```

Symbolically

```
Limit[Power[Sqrt[((1 - 4 n)/(3 n + 2))^(3 n)]^2, (n)^-1], 
   n -> ∞] // FullSimplify // Timing
(* {10.405267, 64/27} *)
```

Note that there are is no need for adding other built-in functions such as `ComplexExpand`, `PowerExpand` and the like.